# Why was the thinline stratocaster never really a thing?

Tags: electric-guitar

I know Eric Johnson has a signature thinline strat but why was the thinline strat never really a thing like the thinline teles were / are?

Why would Fender make a semi-hollow version of the teles for decades but not for their other flagship guitar model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

isnt the stratocaster rather more heavily chamfered* making a chambered version technically quite  difficult to make ?

A tele can easily be made semi-hollow by building the body from two pieces: the main part of the body and then a cap. That’s because the sides are mostly squared off. The contoured edges of the strat body make that a lot harder.

*chamfered refers to the removal of some wood, mainly on the outside cormer where the right arm swings, and also on the back, making it a more snug fit against the chest, or for some, to leave room for an overlarge belly.